# after layout.addView(), code is stopped

Tags: android, layout-inflater

```
try {
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(responseBody.string());
  Elements contentsElements = doc.select("div#bo_v_con > p");

  StringBuilder textContents = new StringBuilder();

  for(Element element : contentsElements) {

     if(element.select("img").size() > 0) {

      if(textContents.length() > 0) {
        Log.i(TAG, textContents.toString());
        View textParent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article_text, articleBody, true);
        TextView textView = textParent.findViewById(R.id.article_text_contents);
        textView.setText(textContents.toString());
        articleBody.addView(textView);
        textContents = new StringBuilder();
        Log.i(TAG, "textView is added");
     }

      Log.i(TAG, element.select("img").attr("src"));
      View imageParent = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.article_image, articleBody, true);
      ImageView imageView = imageParent.findViewById(R.id.article_image_contents);
      GlideApp.with(ArticleActivity.this)
          .load(element.select("img").attr("src"))
          .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
          .into(imageView);

      articleBody.addView(imageParent);
    } else {
      textContents.append(element.text().trim()).append("\n");
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this is my code.

if element have `<img>` tag, add textview with StringBuilder's String before add imageView.

I can't run `Log.i(TAG, "textView is added")` after running `articleBody.addView(textView)`

there is no message, no error. just stopped.

when remove inflate code, `Log.i(TAG, "textView is added")` is run.

what am i missing?

Comment: you have to add layout params to the view you are addinf in your articleBody before adding the view

Comment: add layout params to textParent, imageParent?

Comment: Change `articleBody.addView(textView);` to `articleBody.addView(textParent);`. You can't add a `View` that already has a parent to another `View`.

Comment: yes, if your articleBody let say is linear layout, you need to add the Linearlayout params to textParent and imageParent before adding them to your article

Comment: thank you, @Mike M. @Umar Hussain. I've modified the code according to advice. but I still can not run `Log.i(TAG, "textView is added")`

Comment: Also change the last argument in the `inflate()` call to `false`.

Comment: omg...it works. but its not worked before i asked. lol.....thank you @MikeM.

Comment: No problem. You were getting an `IllegalStateException` there, so if you couldn't see that in your logs, you really should figure out why. Cheers!